# Graphing multiple histograms in one output in grid ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following pseudocode where I want to plot multiple histograms in a 4x8 grid.
The length of vector cols is 32.

When I run this code it doesn't plot anything.

How can I fix this? Do i need to do some sort of facet? Not sure how to proceed.

```
par(mfrow = c(4,8))

cols <- t$label

for (i in cols) {
  
  df |>
  dplyr::filter(label == i) |>
  dplyr::select(count_col) |>
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = count_col)) +
  ggplot2::geom_histogram() +
  ggplot2::ggtitle(i)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use a `facet_wrap` for this.  Look at the toy example below:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(y=rnorm(1000), x=sample(1:32,1000,TRUE))

ggplot(dat, aes(x=y)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~x, ncol=8)
```

[image]